# Unexpected output for np.arange

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np

for _ in np.arange(0, 10, 0.01):
    print(_)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tswyn.png)

Why are there outputs that suddenly have so many decimal places? Is it some kind of rounding off error? [I'm new to python and coding in general. I have snipped a picture for reference] :D

Comment: Please post text instead of images - see [ask].

Comment: Sorry...... I will take note of that in future posts.